# Query uses rank() needs optimization

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from
(
  Select DISTINCT 
    DocManREPORT_View.DOCINPUTDATE,
    DocManREPORT_View.REACTIVATEDATE,
    DocManREPORT_View.TRACENO,
    DocManREPORT_View.CLIENTNAME,
    DocManREPORT_View.DOCUMENTID,DocManREPORT_View.BARCODEID,
    DocManREPORT_View.INPUTMODE,
    DocManREPORT_View.INPUTSOURCE,PI.start_time,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY process_instance_id 
       ORDER BY last_modified_date desc) rank,
    PI.STATUS AS PROCESSSTATUS 
  FROM DocManREPORT_View 
  INNER JOIN PROCESS_INSTANCE PI ON 
    (pi.instance_id = DocManREPORT_View.process_instance_id)
) 
where rank = 1;
```

Comment: are you sure this is the query, it has two "WHERE" clauses?

Comment: It seems you forgot ( somwhere. I presume before WHERE RANK = 1

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect query before. Now I have edited and added the correct one.

Comment: Could you please give some details to your question, what is the current problem? Like you have 10 million rows and it runs 10 min, but you need 1 min. Or something like this would make the question more worthy.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `DISTINCT`? It seems that it's not needed.

Comment: Did you try to use the:

     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY process_instance_id 
           ORDER BY last_modified_date desc) rank,

Inside the VIEW, since I tihnk the View has already every data to make it?

Comment: @AndrásOttó Yes, But not much of a difference and also the view does not have all data to make the needed result

Comment: @ypercube Not a difference in execution plan. And logically distinct is needed to avoid repeating columns of same value in my query logic

Comment: The query runs for nearly 16s for returning 3,94,399 rows. The cost from the execution plan is 263355. The cost must come down to nearly 1000 and the query less than a second. Full table scan happens in PROCESS_INSTANCE and Table on top of which view is created. The objective of using rank in the above query is that to use the process_instance_id which belongs to the latest last_modified_date.

Comment: What are you doing with the data?  That's a lot of rows for a `SELECT`.  Most programs will take at least several seconds just to display that much data.

Answer (score 0):

I presume DISTINCT clause could screw up the performance. I would recommend you to get rid of it by including into partition by clause and have a look what have you got.

Comment: May be it would be good to materialize DISTINCT part using WITH clause?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try to use the

```
 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY process_instance_id 
       ORDER BY last_modified_date desc) rank,
```

Inside the VIEW, since I tihnk the View has already every data to make this step inside.

Comment: View does not have all the data. Some other tables also need to be referred

Comment: last_modifed_date is from an other table?